# C++ template compile failed

Tags: c++, list, templates, vector, compiler-errors

I want write an simple demo, but it compile failed, I can't find the reason.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
using namespace std;


template <
    typename T,  
    template <typename W> typename  Container = std::vector 
>
class myclass
{
public:
    Container<T> myc;

public:
    void func();
    myclass() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            myc.push_back(i);  
        }
    }
};

template <
    typename T,
    template <typename W> typename  Container 
>
void myclass<T, Container>::func()
{
    cout << "good!" << endl;
}


int main()
{
   
    myclass<int, vector> mylistobj2; 
    mylistobj2.func();


    return 0;
}
```

the compile reason is that

```
tmp.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
tmp.cpp:100:30: error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for ‘template<class T, template<class W> class Container> class _nmsp1::myclass’
  100 |  _nmsp1::myclass<double, list> mylistobj2; 
      |                              ^
tmp.cpp:100:30: note:   expected a template of type ‘template<class W> class Container’, got ‘template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::__cxx11::list’
tmp.cpp:101:13: error: request for member ‘func’ in ‘mylistobj2’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
  101 |  mylistobj2.func();
```

Comment: [The `std::vector` template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) doesn't take a single template argument. Neither does [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list). Instead of using template-template arguments, use plain template arguments, like plain `typename Container`. Then use the proper type when using your template, like `myclass<std::list<double>>`. Use `Container::value_type` if you need the type stored in the container (instead of your `T`).

Comment: And a note about writing good questions: Make sure that the error you get actually matches the code you show! Yours doesn't. Create your [mre], then copy-paste the errors from that example.

Comment: Compile with `-std=c++17` and it will work.

Comment: @PasserBy: not with clang though [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/odsfbWv4e).

Answer (score 2):

[`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) has two template parameters (the 2nd one has default argument), while the template template parameter `Container` is declared with only one template parameter. They don't match. You may apply [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

```
template <
    typename T,  
    template <typename...> typename  Container = std::vector 
>
class myclass
{
public:
    Container<T> myc;

public:
    void func();
    myclass() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            myc.push_back(i);  
        }
    }
};

template <
    typename T,
    template <typename...> typename  Container 
>
void myclass<T, Container>::func()
{
    cout << "good!" << endl;
}
```

Your code would work fine with C++17; since C++17 ([CWG 150](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#150)), the default template arguments are allowed for a [template template argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_arguments) to match a template template parameter with fewer template parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that **prior to C++17**

> a template template argument had to be a template with parameters that **exactly match** the parameters of the template template parameter it substitutes with some exceptions related to variadic template parameters.

In your given example this means that since [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) template of the standard library has more than one parameter: The second parameter (which describes an **allocator**) has a **default value**, but prior to C++17 this was not considered when matching `std::vector` to the `Container` parameter.

There are 2 ways to solve this.

##### Solution 1

One solution is to rewrite the class `myclass` declaration so that the `Container` parameter expects containers with two template parameters as shown below:

```
template <typename T,  
    template <typename W,typename Alloc = std::allocator<W>> typename  Container = std::vector> //note the second template parameter Alloc added here 

class myclass
{
public:
    Container<T> myc;

public:
    void func();
    myclass() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            myc.push_back(i);  
        }
    }
};

template <typename T,
    template <typename W, typename Alloc> typename  Container> //note the second template parameter here

void myclass<T, Container>::func()
{
    cout << "good!" << endl;
}
```

The output of the above modified program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/QylOoTlzs).

##### Solution 2

You can make use of **parameter pack** to solve this problem.

```
template <typename T,  
    template <typename...> typename  Container = std::vector> //note we have parameter pack

class myclass
{
public:
    Container<T> myc;

public:
    void func();
    myclass() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            myc.push_back(i);  
        }
    }
};

template <typename T,
    template <typename...> typename  Container> //note we have parameter pack 

void myclass<T, Container>::func()
{
    cout << "good!" << endl;
}
```

The output of the above modified program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/xkcugm1RK).

Note also that your program [works](https://onlinegdb.com/jEDWcYYIw) without any modification with C++17.