# Is omitting template parameter that has a default template argument in a template template parameter legal?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The title may be hard to parse, consider the following code

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template <template<typename> typename C, typename T>
void sort(C<T>& c)
{
  std::sort(c.begin(), c.end());
}

void f()
{
  std::vector vi = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  ::sort(vi);
}
```

`vector` has a second template parameter `Alloc` that has a default template argument.
The template template parameter `C` of `sort` has only one template parameter.
`gcc` compiles this code, while `clang` issues an error of "no matching function to 'sort'" (both with `-std=c++20`).

Which compiler conforms to the standard? Is this code legal?

Comment: If I remember correctly, it depends of standard (pre/post C++17)...

Comment: As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70937201/12002570), post c++17 it can be omitted. The linked answer has the explanation.

Comment: gcc rejects before C++17, and accepts in C++17, whereas clang/msvc reject in all mode. msvc accepts `::sort<std::vector>(vi);` though.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give a reference to the standard where this has changed? Haven't been able to find the relevant section.

Comment: References: [CWG 150](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4457.html#150) (the issue that started it) - [P0522R0](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0522r0.html) the paper that resolved it. - [13.4.4 Template template arguments (3)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.arg.template#3) the current rule in the C++20 standard - [clang template template defaulted parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48447541/8411406) the reason why you need `-frelaxed-template-template-args` with clang - [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/san8qWEGn) working example